# Can I scp a file from a deployed server to my local machine using Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I want to run a command, save the output as a tmp file and copy it back to my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Capistrano 2.3.0, there is are `download` and `upload` commands you can use in your deployment script. Here is the [blog post](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/5/2/capistrano-2-3-0) talking about these features.

```
download "/remote/file", "/local/file"
```

Comment: By default it uses SFTP transfer. You can force SCP by calling `download "/remote/file", "/local/file", via: :scp`